# How to type test using schemas so that TypeScript understands?

Tags: typescript, zod

Let’s say I have a schema like:

```js
export const Book = z.object({
    type: z.literal("book"),
    title: z.string(),
    published: z.number().int()
});
```

How can I check if a value is a `Book` so that TypeScript understands? For example, I want to be able to do:

```js
if (isType(Book, something)) {
    console.log(`The book title was '${something.title}'`)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need this because the return type of `.parse` and `.safeParse` is type-safed

```
const book = Book.parse(something)
//       ^ "Book" or throw exception if it is not
```

```
const result = Book.safeParse(something)
if (result.success) {
  result.data
  //      ^ "Book"
}
```

and here is a `isType` function if the aboves not fulfill your case:

```
function isType<T>(schema:z.ZodType<T>, value: unknown): value is T {
  const result = schema.safeParse(value)
  return result.success
}
```

Comment: The first throws an exception, so it can't be used for type testing. The second doesn't work. The third works but I wish there was a better way.

Comment: for the second one, you have to access `result.data` instead of `something` to get the `Book`